# RXJava 2 Flowable`s mergeWith not merging

Tags: android, rx-java2

I have this method on my Room`s dao

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Expense WHERE date >= :initDate AND date <= :endDate AND chargeableUuid = :chargeableUuid ORDER BY date")
fun currentMonth(initDate: Long, endDate: Long, chargeableUuid: String): Flowable<List<Expense>>
```

and I am using it this way:

```
dao.currentMonth(firstDayOfMonth, lastDayOfMonth, account.uuid)
            .mergeWith(dao.currentMonth(firstDayOfMonth, lastDayOfMonth, card.uuid))
            .subscribe { Log.i("test", "size ${it.size}" }
```

If I execute each call separately both return one element each (different elements), but when I execute them together the log outputs that just one element is in the returned list.

How can I merge the emitions from two Flowables into one?

Comment: But you receive two lists, right?

Comment: @GVillani82 Yes, it is the same method and it returns a Flowable<List<Expense>>

Comment: I mean, in your logcat you'll see two messages with the same text: "size 1"

Comment: @GVillani82 so you are saying that the subscribe method will be called twice? With each emission? I will check it out now :)

Comment: Yes, exactly! If you take a look at how `merge` operator works, you'll see it: http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/merge.html

Comment: @GVillani82 you are right :). So how can I merge both emitions into a single one? With zipWith? Can you post a answer with an example code so I can accept it and give you the reputation you deserve? :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you use the `merge` (or `mergeWith`) operator as you can see in the diagram, you will have an Observable that emits all the items emitted from all the `Observable` (or `Flowable` you are merging).

[image]

So, actually your subscriber will receive two List. If you want just one `Flowable` that emit one single item (a list) containing all the items contained in all the lists, you can use the `toList` operator:

doing

```
dao.currentMonth(firstDayOfMonth, lastDayOfMonth, account.uuid)
            .mergeWith(dao.currentMonth(firstDayOfMonth, lastDayOfMonth, card.uuid))
    .toList()
```

you'll create a `Flowable` that emits a list of list, `List<List< Expense>>` that will contains your two lists. So you can `map` it in a single list:

```
dao.currentMonth(firstDayOfMonth, lastDayOfMonth, account.uuid)
   .mergeWith(dao.currentMonth(firstDayOfMonth, lastDayOfMonth, card.uuid))
    .toList()
    .map(lists -> {
     List<Expense> l = new ArrayList<>();
     for (List<Expense> list : lists) {
          l.addAll(list);
     }
     return l;
})
```

If you subscribe now, you will get a single list containing two `Expense` objects.

Comment: Dude, you are my hero :D

Comment: twice my hero! haha